# How to implement serde::Deserialize on struct containing &'static str?

Tags: string, rust, deserialization, borrow-checker, serde

I'm trying to implement `serde::Deserialize` on a `SourceConfig` struct, which wraps a struct containing an `&'static str` along with having some data of its own [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c3b738fd09f12645d733e631bc9be67c):

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Config {
    pub name: &'static str,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct SourceConfig {
    config: Config,
    id: u32,
}
```

But that gives me a lifetime error:

```text
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'de` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:10:5
   |
10 |     config: Config,
   |     ^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'de` as defined on the impl at 8:21...
  --> src/lib.rs:8:21
   |
8  | #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/lib.rs:10:5
   |
10 |     config: Config,
   |     ^^^^^^
   = note: expected `SeqAccess<'_>`
              found `SeqAccess<'de>`
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/lib.rs:10:5
   |
10 |     config: Config,
   |     ^^^^^^
   = note: expected `Deserialize<'_>`
              found `Deserialize<'static>`
   = note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'de` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:10:5
   |
10 |     config: Config,
   |     ^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'de` as defined on the impl at 8:21...
  --> src/lib.rs:8:21
   |
8  | #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/lib.rs:10:5
   |
10 |     config: Config,
   |     ^^^^^^
   = note: expected `MapAccess<'_>`
              found `MapAccess<'de>`
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/lib.rs:10:5
   |
10 |     config: Config,
   |     ^^^^^^
   = note: expected `Deserialize<'_>`
              found `Deserialize<'static>`
   = note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

I tried adding `#[serde(borrow)]` to the `config` in `SourceConfig`, but that doesn't work since `Config` isn't borrowed. Adding it to the `name` in `Config` doesn't work either. How can I correctly implement `Deserialize` on `SourceConfig`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a [bound](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#bound) on the `SourceConfig` struct, such that the `'de` lifetime is equal to the `'static` lifetime.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, serde::Deserialize)]
pub struct Config {
    pub name: &'static str,
}

#[derive(Debug, serde::Deserialize)]
#[serde(bound(deserialize = "'de: 'static"))]
struct SourceConfig {
    config: Config,
    id: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let j = r#"
{
    "id": 123,
    "config": {
        "name": "John Smith"
    }
}
    "#;
    
    let sc: SourceConfig = serde_json::from_str(&j).unwrap();
    dbg!(sc);
}
```

However, you probably do not want to deserialize a `&'static str` since that requires that you have a `&'static str` to borrow from. This limits you to either string literals, or you need to leak memory to acquire a `&'static str`.
You likely want a `String` or, if you want to support string literals, a `Cow<'a, str>`.

Another problem with `&'a str` is that it will not work if the string is serialized with escape sequences. For example a JSON string containing a line-break will have `\n` which need to be replaced during deserialization thus failing if you use `&'a str`.

Comment: great answer. thanks.
I could get it to work the other way around:
#[serde(bound(deserialize = "'static: 'de"))]

Comment: I hadn't thought about the `\n` case! Here's the error `serde_json` gives when there is something like `\n` in the JSON: `Error("invalid type: string \"John\\nSmith\", expected a borrowed string", line: 5, column: 29)`