# Problem in String to (&'static str) conversion while Implementing Custom Serialization in Serde Rust

Tags: string, serialization, rust, lifetime, serde

I am trying to use the custom implementation in `Serialize` trait of `Serde`. Here is the code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c6823a92c003a740ba83777bfa924be0)):

```rust
use serde::ser::{Serialize, Serializer, SerializeStruct};

struct Data {
    key: String,    // or &str
    value: i32,
}

impl Serialize for Data {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let mut state = serializer.serialize_struct("Data", 1)?;

        // let key = (&self.key).to_string();
        // state.serialize_field(&*key, &self.value)?;  //shows lifetime error
      
        state.serialize_field("key", &self.value)?;
        state.end()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data = Data {
        key: String::from("age"),
        value: 21,
    };

    let json = serde_json::to_string_pretty(&data).unwrap();

    println!("the JSON is: {}", json)
}
```

by default, `serde` serialize `Data` as:

```json
{
  "key": "age",
  "value": 21
}
```

but, i want this:

```json
{
  "age": 21,
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67650170/how-to-implement-serdedeserialize-on-struct-containing-static-str) is also similar, but I need more info in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Data` struct is essentially a singleton map. You should serialize it as such:

```rust
impl Serialize for Data {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        use serde::ser::SerializeMap;
        let mut map = serializer.serialize_map(Some(1))?;
        map.serialize_entry(&self.key, &self.value)?;
        map.end()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f00a3fcad838eb4377864086ec102386)
The crucial difference being that `serialize_entry` takes an `&K` where `K: Serialize` (i.e. a reference with an arbitrary lifetime), unlike `serialize_field`, which doesn't expect that you come up with new struct fields at run-time and is built for compile-time constant strings, which are `&'static str`.